# The same IP (public) from outside the container as well as from inside the container

Tags: linux, docker

I'm trying to make a Docker container accessible on e.g. `1.2.3.4:9999:99` from the Internet (so from outside the container) to be seen as the same IP from inside so when I'm inside the container and doing `curl http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com/` I would get `1.2.3.4`. I'm struggling with it for hours and no progress.

I'm running the container with `docker run --name public254 -d -p 123.456.789.254:22:22 some-image:latest` and it's accessible through `123.456.789.254` indeed. When inside it's seen as the main IP of the host as it's supposed to.

Now I want to modify this. What should I do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I did it.

1. Enable forwarding
   `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`
2. Find out container's internal IP
   `docker inspect -f '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' some_container`
3. Route it correctly
   `iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -p all -s <container internal IP> -j SNAT --to-source <container external IP>`